# Which version of handlebar uses Ember RC 6?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I started updating my web app from ember and handlebar rc3 to ember rc6 and handlebar 1.0.

But I've have troubles executing my web app in the method:

```
quotedString: function(str) { ... }
```

of handlebars. Its seams that the str its undefined in some cases.

Even putting an if condition that verified if the str its undefined my app wasn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the handlebars version mentioned on the ember.js homepage for rc6, the link is http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js

Hope it helps.